# how to program qb64 bullet point

Tags: ascii, qb64

Is there an ASCII code for placing a bullet point in text that can be used to program QB64 with the `CHR$(XXX)` command?

I have tried `CHR$(ALT + 0149)` but the `ALT` doesn't change it from `CHR$(149)`.

Comment: Specifying ALT only adds 0 to 149 as it is treated like a variable.

Comment: The ascii code chart: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: ALT-149 could be CHR$(0)+CHR$(149) but this is a keyboard scan code not an ascii character.

Answer (score 1):

Any ascii character from 0 - 31 can be displayed when used as such in qb64:

```
REM display an ascii char
_CONTROLCHR OFF ' turn off control code processing
PRINT CHR$(7) ' treat control code as a character
_CONTROLCHR ON
```